# Is there any easy way to replace one data in plist?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, plist

Here is how I can get the value:

```
NSString *path =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *tempArray = [dict valueForKey:@"2"];
NSString *myTarget = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

the "myTarget" is something I want to replace with, how can I replace it with @"newString" and write to plist? thz u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSString *path =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                    propertyListFromData:data
                                    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                    format:NULL
                                    errorDescription:NULL];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [dict valueForKey:@"2"];
NSString *myTarget = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
[tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newString];
[dict writeToFile:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
```